# Using while True miltiple times

Tags: python

I'm new here and this is my first question. Apologies for any shortcomings.

I'm trying practise using a simply code. This example has the below output:

```
*who are you?  
Joe  
Hello Joe. What is the password? (It is a fish)  
hoki  
Access granted  
Hello Joe. What is the password? (It is a fish)*
```

The code I am using is:

```py
while True:
    print('who are you?')
    name = input()
    if name != 'Joe':
        continue
    while True:
        print('Hello Joe. What is the password? (It is a fish)')
        password = input()
        if password !='hoki':
            continue
        print('Access granted')*
```

As im trying to get out of the second `while True` loop using the continue statement (if the answer to the password question is `hoki`) it asks again `"Hello Joe. What is the password? (It is a fish)*`
It should be ending and not asking me for the password again as I've entered the correct one.

Any advice is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Use break to terminate the loop https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/break-continue

Answer (score 3):

Here's the solution

```
user_check = True
while user_check:
    print('who are you?')
    name = input()
    if name != 'Joe':
        continue
    while True:
        print('Hello Joe. What is the password? (It is a fish)')
        password = input()
        if password !='hoki':
            continue
        else:
            print('Access granted')
            user_check = False
            break
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a break statement in your code to end the loop.

```
while True:
    print('This loop will stop because of my break statement!')
    break

print('This will print out because we used the break statement!')
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem with your code is that it is just using `continue`. There is no statement for program to break out of the `while-loop`.

You just need two `break` statements, like this:

```
while True:
    print('who are you?')
    name = input()
    if name != 'Joe':
        continue
    while True:
        print('Hello Joe. What is the password? (It is a fish)')
        password = input()
        if password !='hoki':
            continue
        print('Access granted')
        break # break inner loop
    break # break outer loop
```

Comment: Yep perfect was missing the breaks to close the while loops.

Answer (score 0):

Like some others said you should use `break` instead of `continue` but you'll also need to change your password check to be `password == 'hoki'

Comment: Yeh I'm actually using an example from a book which used break and I thought I'd play around with continue.

Answer (score 0):

1. remove the `*` before the first `while` statement, and after the `print('Access granted`)
2. indent all code that follows so that it is executed within the `while` loop.
3. finally, add break statements as per below:

```py
while True:
    print('who are you?')
    name = input()
    if name != 'Joe':
        continue
    while True:
        print('Hello Joe. What is the password? (It is a fish)')
        password = input()
        if password !='hoki':
            continue
        print('Access granted')
        break
    break
```

This should give the desired outcome. A more "semantic" way of solving the problem might be this:

```py
logged_in = False

while not logged_in:
    print('who are you?')
    name = input()
    if name == 'Joe':
        while not logged_in:
            print('Hello Joe. What is the password? (It is a fish)')
            password = input()
            if password =='hoki':
                print('Access granted')
                logged_in = True

# Code only accessible to logged-in user
print("Now let's do some things that only Joe can do...")
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yep definitely did. This answer and the other ones advising the use of the 2 missing breaks helped my understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a While True directly; make it While (variable). Then proceed with your logic. See example below:

```
a = True

while a:

     # apply logic
     # if you want to break this loop; assign False to a.

     b = True

     while b:

         # apply logic
         # if you want to break this loop; assign False to b


         # .... and so on
```

Hope this is helpful.